# Basically need to subtract two datasets in base sas (proc sql)

Tags: sas, dataset

First I have created dataset 'have'. Then I sorted this dataset(have).
Again created a dataset 'havenot'.Now basically,I need to subtract two datasets('have' and 'havenot').

```
data have;
input party_ID  Preference_ID:$11.;
datalines;
 101 Preference1
 101 Preference2
 102 Preference4
 102 Preference1
 102 Preference5
;

proc sort data = have;
by party_ID Preference_ID;
run;

data havenot;
set have;
by party_ID Preference_ID;
if first.party_id;
run;
```

(output of havenot)

```
party_ID Preferenece_ID
101 Preference1
102 Preference1
```

Desired output that I want

```
party_ID Preference_ID
101 Preference2
102 Preference4
102 Preference5
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to remove the first record per PARTY_ID?

You could just reverse the logic in your subsetting IF statement.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by party_id;
  if not first.party_id;
run;
```

Or another way is to explicitly delete the first observations.

```
if first.party_id then delete;
```

If you are asking how to remove exact row matches then PROC SQL can do that.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select * from have
    except
    select * from havenot
  ;
quit;
```

If you want to remove rows based on just key matches then might be better in a data step.

```
data want ;
   merge have havenot(in=in2 keep=party_id preference_id);
   by party_id preference_id;
   if not in2;
run;
```

Comment: For SQL the `except` set operator is correct. [Producing Rows That Are in Only the First Query Result (EXCEPT)](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n0vo2lglyrnexwn14emi8m0jqvrj.htm&locale=en#p0z77biv9zjqpvn11y9tgxb6cz4x).  If the two table have different columns a negated existential sub-query would be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can do  if not first.variable will give the dataset you want

```
data other;
  set have;
by party_ID Preference_ID;
if not first.party_id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use a data step:

```
data output;
  merge have(in=i1) havenot(in=i2);
  by party_ID Preference_ID;
  if not i2;
run;
```

If you want to use proc sql, you could do the following:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table output as
  select a.*
  from have as a
  full outer join havenot as b
  on a.party_ID eq b.party_ID and a.Preference_ID eq b.Preference_ID
  where b.party_ID is missing;
quit;
```